# como retornar con javascript linea de HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5

quiero retornar en una funcion `javascript` `html`.

Esto es lo que he podido hacer hasta el momento pero no me esta funcionando

primeramente tengo esta linea que adiciona en una tabla algunos datos con javascript

```
$('#lista_direcciones').append('<tr id="' + direccion.id_count + '"><td style="text-align: center">' + direccionCompleta(direccion, data.localidad) + '</td><td style="text-align: center"><div id="actual">' + esActual(direccion.es_actual) + '</div></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="eliminarDireccion(\'' + direccion.id_count + '\');"></buton></td></tr>');
```

La funcion esActual revisa si una direccion es actual o no y la idea es retornar codigo `html`

```
function esActual(es_actual) {

        if (es_actual === 1) {

            return "Es anterior";
        } else {
            return "Es Actual"
        }
    }
```

Como puedo retornar `HTML` con la función esActual

Comment: por que no simplemente haces return "<div>y aqui mas codigo html</div>"

Comment: No está claro lo que está preguntando, pero vamos de apoco  ¿Cuál es el HTML  que quieres retornar?

Answer (score 0):

```js
;(function($){

var actuales = 0;

$("#esActual").append( 
  esActual(true) 
).after(function(){
$('#i'+actuales).off('click');
$('#i'+actuales).on('click',function(){console.log('daddy listen !');});
});



function esActual() {
 if ( arguments[0] === true ) {
  const HTMLActual = $('<div />').append(
    $('<div />',{
      class: 'custom-class',
      style: 'width: 100%; display:flex; justify-content:space-around'
    }).append(
      $('<p />',{
        text: 'hellouda!'
      })
    ).append(
      $('<p />',{
        text: 'hellouda sibling!'
      }).append(
        $('<button />',{
          id: 'i'+(++actuales),
          text: 'hey daddy !! :\') '
        })
    )).clone()
  ).html();
   

   return HTMLActual;
 }
}

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="esActual"></div>
```